# HTML elements position changes when new elements appear

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a webpage which initially looks like this.

[image]

When clicked upon a link, a small form appears to the right side of the page.

[image]

[image]

The problem is when that happens that line which reads **Record added** also moves to the middle.

These are the CSS rules I've written to position them.

```
#frmAddService { float:right; padding-right:250px; padding-top:150px; }   //the form

#msg { float:right; padding-right:250px; padding-top:300px; }   //the 'Record Added' line
```

How can I make that line's position fixed when the form appears?

Thank you.

Comment: can you crate a http://jsfiddle.net/. do not use Padding-top. for sure the element won`t have enough space

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nK0de/PJVu6/)'s a fiddle. Please maximize the **Result** window and you can get an idea on what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool thank for the link, that help :)

I created a new div and add your form and your msg in it. that way, if one move both move.
And I put the id, formContainer.

here is the CSS

```
#formContainer{width:350px; float:right;padding-right:250px;}
#frmAddService {position: relative; float:right;padding-top:300px;}

#msg { position:relative; float:right; padding-top:300px; }

#tasks { float:left; padding-left:40px; padding-top:100px; }​
```

I also moddify your Jquery to change the value of your #msg

```
$(function()
{
    $("#frmAddService").hide();

    $("#add").click(function()
    {
        $("#frmAddService").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#msg").css("padding-top","0px");
        $("#msg").css("margin-top","10px");
        $("#msg").css("padding-right","100px");
        return false;
    });
});
```

and this mostly it as you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/PJVu6/29/ it work fine.

```
​
```

Comment: If I remove the `padding-top:300px;` and replace it with `margin-top:10px;`, the _Record Added_ line moves to the top of the page. Please see the fiddle I posted as a reply to your previous comment to see the HTML structure.

Comment: you may just need to add more parring-right when it`s on click to center it or put it where you want your #msg.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I took an idea from your code and did this. I put `position:relative;` for `#msg` and in the jQuery code, I added this line `$('#msg').css('left', '200px');`. It gives the results I am okay with for now. But I have to find a way to remove these chunks of spaces taken up by paddings and margins. Anyway, thanks for your help. Appreciate it :)